# AspNet MVC bounces me back to login AFTER rendering default view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

After a successful login using Aspnet Identity (SignInStatus.Success), MVC goes through the entire code of the default action and view, but then mysteriously bounces me back to the login page.

Strangely, this only happens with one of my user roles. I have two roles, **admin** and **editor**. **admin** works fine. **editor** USED to work.

Here's my default view authorization code...

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Editor")]
public ActionResult Index()
{ ...
```

If anyone could suggest what the problem could be, or how I could debug it, that would be much appreciated. I've hit a brick wall. The debugger steps without errors right through the action code, the view code, and the layout code right to the last line of Razor in the layout, which is

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

I've tried it on two different browsers. I thought it might be an issue with the anti-forgery token. I did get the following message once...
"The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user".

But I think this was just a glitch from so many login attempts during debugging.

I'm running...
VS 2015
.NET Framework 4.5.2
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin all version 2.2.1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show default view controller / authentication code?

Comment: AFAIK, expired AntiForgeryToken key will redirect user to login page if you set default exception handler to that page. Please show your controller, view & any related code which caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Kamo I've added the ActionResult method's authorization code, I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto, hopefully the AntiForgeryToken should not be expired as I just logged in. In terms of showing code: the action mostly calls some quite lengthy methods that build the content, and the layout and view contain A LOT of HTML and Razor, and quite a few Partial Views as this is from a CMS. If I showed it all here the question would become unmanageable. Am happy to show specific pieces of code, and/or watch values.

Comment: You are only Authorizing the Action Index, it is probably going to another Action somewhere not Authorized "Editor" try Authorize entire Controller and see if still happens

Comment: Thanks @MarkHomer did that, didn't fix it. But you got me thinking, so I did a search of [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")], and sure enough, I found a partial view in another controller (using that authorization) that was getting called by my layout. Problem solved! I will publish the full answer below.

Comment: @clayRay cool glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the controller and the view authorized the **Editor** role, my layout was calling an action in another controller using

```
@Html.Action(...
```

That controller had

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

above its class definition.

Hence DotNet decided (even though it had continued through the rendering code for the entire view and layout) to bounce back to the login page.

Thanks to @MarkHomer. His comment gave me the idea to look for this.

I fixed the problem by putting [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Editor")] above the class definition and then setting [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] for individual actions that only needed admin access.

Answer (score 0):

You must be redirecting the user to a RedirectURL post successful login. Have you checked that your logged-in user persists during this redirection or once it gets to the redirected URL.